# Subtract two dataframes for only matching columns

Tags: r

Quick question,

if I have two dataframes with overlapping columns that don't match in order, such as:

```
df1
Chocolate    Strawberry
2            15
3            10
4            5

df2
Strawberry   Chocolate     Vanilla
14           4             30
9            4             15.2
5            4             10
```

And I wanted to subtract the two dataframes for only the matching columns and ignore any columns that aren't overlapping.

Desired result:

```
Chocolate     Strawberry
-2            1
-1            1
 0            0
```

Sample Code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(chocolate = c(2,3,4), strawberry = c(15,10,5))
df2 <- data.frame(strawberry = c(14,9,5), chocolate = c(4,4,4), vanilla = c(30,15.2,10))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `intersect` to get the common columns and then `sort` them so that the columns are in same order while subtracting irrespective of their order in their respective data frames (`df1` and `df2`).

```
cols <- sort(intersect(names(df1), names(df2)))
df1[cols] - df2[cols]

#  chocolate strawberry
#1        -2          1
#2        -1          1
#3         0          0
```

Comment: Works great - thanks! Want to push it one step further, what is the column names weren't exactly the same? Say if df1 had "chocolate" and df2 had "chocolateCount" - is it possible to match column names in a "like" manner through dplyr?

Comment: @S31 yes, you can use some variation of `grepl` for getting "like" columns together.

Comment: but the code does not works if both the dataframes has same text IDs @Ronak Shah